# Commas in calculator app for windows 8 app store

Tags: windows, vb.net, calculator

I've been scouring the web looking for code that will allow my calculator to have commas in it. I have found some code, but visual studio 2012 won't allow me to use it. I've also beem to MSDN where it talks about using "N" so that the app understands the characters are numbers and formats them properly, but where do I even put that code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
Dim Value = 1234567.0123
Dim DisplayText = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0.#####}", Value)
```

`DisplayText` now contains the string `1,234,567.0123`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Maybe I'm placing that code in the wrong place? It's weird. I can get it to work on the negate button (-/+) by using the code: lblDisplay.Text = answer.ToString("N")

Comment: You'll need to give a little more information to track it down then. What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Exception? Won't Compile? Does nothing? If it does nothing then you're not putting the code in the right place. If it won't compile, it's likely a typo. If there's an exception, please tell us what it is